# Objective-C: Forward most messages to another object (at runtime)

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

### Subclass of `UIView`

I have a subclass `MyView` of `UIView`.

This subclass has a `@property UIView * realView`.

### What I want to do

Whenever a message is sent to `MyView`, I want to "forward it" to `self.realView`, excepted for few messages.

For instance, in the implementation of `MyView`, I would have this override:

```
- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color
{
     [self.realView setBackgroundColor:color] ;
}
```

**Instead of overriding explicitly all the methods, can I do it automatically, at the runtime?**

### Exceptions

For some methods, I want to have an explicit control. For instance:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    /* do stuff */
    
    [super setFrame:frame] ;
}
```

Comment: Check this out! https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-27-objective-c-message-forwarding.html

Comment: It might help to know why you want one view instance to forward messages to another instead of handling the messages itself. That's seems highly unusual. Also, what criteria are you using to determine which messages to forward?

Answer (score 4):

> Instead of overriding explicitly all the methods, can I do it automatically, at the runtime?

You implement the `-forwardInvocation:` method to send any unrecognized messages to the other object. [`-forwardInvocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-forwardInvocation_) is called whenever an object doesn't implement the selector that's passed to it as a sort of second chance to handle a message. You can override it to send the message to another object (which is pretty much what NSProxy does), log the messages, etc.

As @cobbal points out below, `-forwardInvocation` will help you with methods not implemented in your superview, but it won't handle methods that *are* implemented int the superview because your `MyView` inherits implementations of those. For example, if you want to use a `UIView` as a proxy for a `UIButton`, all the methods specific to `UIButton` can be handled by `-forwardInvocation:`, but those defined by `UIView` cannot. In order to get a behavior other than the inherited method, you will of course need to override. In some situations you can get around that by deriving `MyView` from `NSObject` or `UIResponder` instead of from `UIView`, thus avoiding the inherited `UIView` implementations, but if `MyView` needs to be a real view you're stuck with overriding each method.

If you think about it, it's hard to imagine how your goal could be met without explicitly overriding each inherited method. You say that you only want to forward *most* messages, but how can the poor runtime tell which ones you do want to forward and which ones you don't? All it can do is look for a method for the given selector and call it if it finds one, or take some action (like calling `-forwardInvocation:`) if it doesn't.

**Update:** @robmayoff points out `-forwardingTargetForSelector:`, which didn't occur to me but is probably a better solution in your case. It still doesn't handle the situation where you need to redirect methods that you inherit from a superclass, though.

Comment: This won't work for standard view methods, since the superclass (UIView) will handle them and `-forwardInvocation:` will never get called

Comment: @cobbal That's true -- the OP will have to override methods that are defined in the superclass. I'll update to mention that.

Comment: as both classes are UIViews and the subclassed one is responding first, it would be all methods that need to be called manually.

Comment: Also note that `forwardingTargetForSelector:` is both much simpler to implement and much more efficient at runtime.

Comment: Maybe I could write a macro which take a string like `"setSubviews:"` and that automatically writes the `forwardingTarget...`

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible. 
First you need [WZProtocolIntercepter](https://github.com/haifengkao/WZProtocolInterceptor). Then use the intercepter as the normal UIView:

```
WZProtocolInterceptor* fakeView = [[WZProtocolInterceptor alloc]
                                  initWithInterceptedProtocol:@protocol(TheMethodsForTheMiddleManToHandle)];

fakeView.receiver = self.realView;
fakeView.middleMan = self;
[someViewController.view addSubview:fakeView];
```

Put the methods you want to control in `TheMethodsForTheMiddleManToHandle`:

```
@protocol TheMethodsForTheMiddleManToHandle
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame;
@end
```